# matplotlib - wxpython backend - fast update

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

As part of a big GUI effort that is meant to plotting complex scientific figures I am trying to speed up interactions and figure updates. So far I've been using canvas.draw() method to update any changes to any drawn object in the figure. 
I won't be able to reproduce an example code as it's a thousands lines of code but this is a snapshot of what I am dealing with

[image]

the above figure is a fairly congested example image with 3 Axes, contour plot, path, arrow, png image, different transparency objects, shadows, lines, fills, colorbar, etc

[image]

normally a user will be playing with a GUI like the one above to add, delete update or modify any plotted object. 
For such a figure any modification is slow because it calls canvas.draw() at the backend.

```
#self.__canvas.Refresh()
#self.__canvas.Update()
###self.__canvas.update() # 'FigureCanvasWxAgg' object has no attribute 'update'
#self.__canvas.Refresh()
#self.__canvas.flush_events()
#self.__canvas.blit(self.__selectedAxes.bbox)
self.__canvas.draw()
```

I have tried using all the above but only canvas.draw results in updating the figure all the others won't. So far I am not sure how to speed up re-drawing the image after updating only one object.

Also, according to this [post](http://bastibe.de/2013-05-30-speeding-up-matplotlib.html) blit results in memory leaks. Did anyone tried to verify this hypothesis ?

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: For this example case you probably do not want to use blitting, since you want to show the complete figure and be able to save it etc. The draw time is roughly linear with the number of artists to draw, images with lots of points or complex things as shadows will of course increase draw time drastically. First note: Matplotlib is not optimized for fast drawing. If that is an issue, other libraries might be better suited. Second note: If this is about user experience, just deal with the draw time ergonoically, show a progress bar or similar to inform the user that there is something going on.

Comment: In general `canvas.draw_idle()` should be preferred over `canvas.draw()`. This will not speed up a single draw, but would prevent several draw_events queueing up.

Comment: thank you for your comments, I've been looking closely at the code and not being able to pin point what I can do to get faster at updating only 1 artist instead of redrawing all of them. helas no luck so far.

Comment: I just ran through gr as a fast backend to matplotlib. still giving me hard time to run but will see how it goes and if i will be able to make wxpython matplotlib and gr work together in a harmony

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `self.__canvas.draw()`and redrawing all data on the plots, you can use blitting. By useage of blitting you can add specific new elements to a plot instead of redrawing the whole thing. This saves a massive amount of time.

In order to start blitting, the canvas has to be drawn at least once somewhere in your code. Otherwise there will be nothing 'to blit to'. So unfortunately you can't get fully rid of `self.__canvas.draw()`.

To blit a certain element, for example a rectangle, you will first have to add the rectangle element to the axes. A rectangle is a matplotlib.patch and to add a patch to the axes you will have to use: `self.axes.add_patch(rectangle)`. Once added you will need to draw it on the axes by using: `self.axes.draw_artist(rectangle)`. After it has been drawn, you can blit it to the canvas using: `self.canvas.blit(self.axes.bbox)`. 
Save the plot with the blitted element as a background image using: `self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.axes.bbox)` and restore it to your canvas using: `self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)`.

Some example code that blits a Rectangle to the canvas:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend.wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

import wx

class Panel(wx.Frame):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Title')

    self.figure = Figure()
    self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
    self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, proportion=1, flag= wx.ALL | wx.GROW)

    """Plot data and stuff to canvas...."""        

    self.canvas.draw()
    self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.axes.bbox)

    square = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((xPos,yPos), width, height)

    self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
    self.axes.add_patch(square)
    self.axes.draw_artist(square)
    self.canvas.blit(self.axes.bbox)
    self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.axes.bbox)
```

Can be I made some typos. But you will get the idea of it.

Comment: There are already some answers on SO which show how to use blitting. So it is questionable if this answer has actually anything to add to those.

Comment: I know, but those do not include wxPython.